# not able to install elementary os (xps 13, 9300, developer edition)

Tags: boot

Hello (: hope somebody can help me.
I made a boot USB with rufus on a windows PC, like it is described on the elementary OS homepage.
After booting on my xps 13 (ubuntu 18.04. LTS preinstalled), there appears the "e" icon. But immediately after that it shows me the ubuntu desktop with following information:

[image: Dell recovery Media]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Select Legacy option in Boot List Option
Under Boot Sequence uncheck Diskette Drive option.

Disable Secure Boot
    To disable it, Go to Secure Boot > Secure Boot Enable > Select Disabled radio

Now reboot the computer, and boot from your bootable device with Try Ubuntu without installation option

Install GParted application and delete first partition from it
Now you can able to install Ubuntu without any error
**not sure whats on the first partition but I asume thats the recovery partition. Not sure if you need this. Please check before deleting**

check: https://askubuntu.com/questions/769634/error-this-recovery-media-only-functions-on-dell-and-alienware-systems

Comment: thanks! Meanwhile I solved it in the following way: first I installed Pop OS instead of ubuntu 18.04 and then after this elementary OS. Both without any problems and "out of the box" (: